# How to escape spaces in a PowerShell one-liner

Tags: windows, powershell, escaping, quoting

I want to run an exe with params using powershell one line, like this -

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted "Start-Process -Path program.exe -ArgumentList somefile.txt, Run"
```

And it works, but when I am trying to insert full path with spaces it's crashing

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted "Start-Process -Path program.exe -ArgumentList "C:\Program Files\somefile.txt", "Run" "
```

I tried to use single quote or escape with ` but it's not helping

Maybe someone know what I do wrong?

P.s. running from inside cmd.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to **use *single*-quoting (`'...'`)** for the embedded strings:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted "Start-Process -Path program.exe -ArgumentList 'C:\Program Files\somefile.txt', 'Run'"
```

Since it is PowerShell that will be interpreting the command string, it recognizes the embedded `'...'` strings as string literals.

---

If you try to embed *double*-quoted strings (`"..."`), you face two hurdles:

- First, PowerShell's *CLI* requires `\` as the escape character for `"` (whereas *internally* it is `` ` ``), so you need to escape the `"` inside the overall `"..."` command string as `\"`.
- *Additionally*, due to a [known problem with `Start-Process`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576), you need an *extra* round of escaping, which makes the solution quite obscure and unwieldy, because **you must escape each embedded `"` as `` \"`\" ``** (!).

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted "Start-Process -Path program.exe -ArgumentList \"`\"C:\Program Files\somefile.txt\"`\", \"`\"Run\"`\" "
```